# Removing nested matches in F#?

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

Suppose I have types like this:

```
type C = 
  | W of int
  | Z of int

type B = 
  {
    C : C
    D : int
  }

type A = 
  | X of int
  | Y of B
```

And I would like to do something for the `Z` case *only*:

```
let a = 
  Y 
    { 
      C = Z 123 
      D = 456
    }

match a with
| X _ -> ()
| Y b -> 
  match b.C with
  | W _ -> ()
  | Z z -> printfn "%i" z
```

Is there a way to achieve this in a single `match`?

Can this be made more concise?

Comment: you could always roll some Active Patterns if it gets too complex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is indeed! Patterns can be *nested*, that's their primary point. You can match on `Y`, and inside that match on the fields of `B`, and inside that match on `C`.

Like this:

```
match a with
| X _ -> ()
| Y { C = Z z } -> printfn "%i" z
| Y { C = W _ } -> ()
```

And since you're returning unit in both non-`Y.C.Z` cases, you can combine them in a catch-all pattern:

```
match a with
| Y { C = Z z } -> printfn "%i" z
| _ -> ()
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this only works on records. You cannot match object or interface properties.

Comment: The above ^ was in response to another comment, now deleted, that stated: "I didn't realize you could match on record fields"